# accessing map values

Tags: groovy, dictionary

Hi I have the following map called `allLang[:]` when I print out all the contents of the map using `println allLang` I get the following output:

```
[1:[en, de], 2:[en, de], 3:[en, de], 4:[en, de], 5:[en, de], 6:[en, de], 7:[en,
de], 8:[en], 9:[en], 10:[en, de], 11:[en, de], 12:[en, de], 13:[en, de], 14:[en,
 de], 15:[en], 16:[en], 17:[en], 18:[en], 19:[en], 27:[de], 33:[de], 34:[de], 35
:[de], 36:[de]]
```

however when I try to print out the value attached to a specific key for example:

```
println allLang[2]
```

the output is null. I tried to access that value in multiple ways:

```
println allLang['2']
println allLang.get(2)
println allLang.get('2')
```

and neither of these work, I still get null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you define the array? Could it be that the index is not '2' but ' 2' (or some other non printable character)?

the easiest way to find out is to...

- `println allLang.inspect()`

this will give you a better output:

```
def allLang = [1:['en','de'],'2':['en','de'],3:['en','de']]
println allLang.inspect()

=> [1:["en", "de"], "2":["en", "de"], 3:["en", "de"]]
```

- or you can iterate through the map and examine the keys:

  allLang.each {key, value ->
    println key.dump()
  }

  `=> <java.lang.Integer@1 value=1>`

  `=> <java.lang.String@32 value=2 offset=0 count=1 hash=50>`

  `=> <java.lang.Integer@3 value=3>`

this should help you to find the right index....

**Update:** got it! The following code reproduces your problem:

```
def allLang = [:] 
def codes = ['en','de']
def query = [0:[id:0l],1:[id:1l],2:[id:2l],3:[id:3l],4:[id:4l]]; 
for(def i = 0; i < query.size(); i++){ 
  allLang[(query[i].id)] = codes; 
}
println allLang
println allLang[2]
println allLang['2']
```

The solution is, that the ´id`used by hibernate is a`Long`. So you have to access your map through long values:

```
println allLang[2l]
```

the best solution to avoid your problem is to avoid numerical indices:

```
allLang[''+(query[i].id)] = codes;
```

will let you access your map through

```
println allLang['2']
```

Comment: when I print it using the .inspect() method I get the following output: `[1:["en", "de"], 2:["en", "de"], 3:["en", "de"], 4:["en", "de"], 5:["en", "de"],
 6:["en", "de"], 7:["en", "de"], 8:["en"], 9:["en"], 10:["en", "de"], 11:["en",
"de"], 12:["en", "de"], 13:["en", "de"], 14:["en", "de"], 15:["en"], 16:["en"],
17:["en"], 18:["en"], 19:["en"], 27:["de"], 33:["de"], 34:["de"], 35:["de"], 36:
["de"]]`

Comment: so it looks like the index is an integer and `println allLang[2]` should work. How do you define the map?

Comment: i defined an empty static map `static allLang = [:]`, and I slowly filled it up with the right key-value pair

Comment: please post an example how you add the key-value pairs. I would like to reproduce the problem in my groovy console...

Comment: `static allLang = [:]                                                def query = Domain.list();                                           for(def i = 0; i < query.size(); i++){                                           allLang[(query[i].id)] = codes;                                       }`                                                               where codes is a list of language codes that are related to the entry with the given id

Comment: hm. could the problem be the `static` modifier? Do you add your values by doing a `allLang[2]=['en','de']` or by doing a `allLang << [2:['en','de']]`? Without more code it will be hard to help...